# avoid showing values in url with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, spring-security

I am making ajax call to login with spring security but it shows username and password in the url no matter what.

ex: `/?j_username=s&j_password=s`

I am trying to find my mistake for a long time but I couldnt be able to see it. It is probably a small mistake.

here is my ajax call;

```
    function performLogin() {
        var j_username = $("#j_username").val();
        var j_password = $("#j_password").val();

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/login",
            crossDomain: true,
            async: false,
            data: { 'j_username': j_username, 'j_password': j_password},
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("x-ajax-call", "no-cache");
            }
        });
    }


Thanks

EDIT: 

It is resolved by adding `return false;` 

But I am not sure if my approach is good. Here is the update;

'function performLogin() {

    var j_username = $("#j_username").val();
    var j_password = $("#j_password").val();

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Mojoping2/login",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        data: { 'j_username': j_username, 'j_password': j_password},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("x-ajax-call", "no-cache");
        },
        success: window.location.reload()

    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: what if replace `data: { 'j_username': j_username, 'j_password': j_password}` with `data: JSON.stringify({ 'j_username': j_username, 'j_password': j_password})`

Comment: Just tested your code and it appears to be POSTing normally for me (ie. no get params in the url called by AJAX) demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5EXWT/

Comment: It should not be putting them in the URL. Is it being switched to a GET somehow?

Comment: @nikis when i replace it, i couldnt login. Cant pass the values. Do you have any idea why it is not posting like the demo on my local ?

Comment: @epascarello i dont think so. My controller is request post and when i change one of them to the GET i am getting warning and lost the communication. Anyway, the url is still changing with the parameters. Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: What URL is changing? the Ajax call or the current page?

Comment: @epascarello ajax call is made succesfully but the url for current page is changing. http://localhost:8080/home to http://localhost:8080/home/?j_username=asdsad&j_password=asdasd

Comment: @epascarello i just realized that it is not related with my ajax call. i command all the function but still URL is changing. Is it possible related to html ?

Comment: I answered it below, if I knew how you called `performLogin`, I could have given you a better answer.

Comment: @epascarello it helped a little bit. I adedd how I am calling `performLogin` as a comment to your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the Ajax call. You are not cancelling the form submission!

```
function performLogin() {
    var j_username = $("#j_username").val();
    var j_password = $("#j_password").val();

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/login",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        data: { 'j_username': j_username, 'j_password': j_password},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("x-ajax-call", "no-cache");
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

and however you are adding the event

```
onsubmit="return performLogin();
```

If you are using jQuery to attach the event, you can use

```
function performLogin(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: I was calling function as `<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="performLogin()"/>` inside the form tag. Now I am calling as `onclick="return performLogin();"`. 

When I return false, paremeters are not added to URL which is what I want. But the problem is ( or because of my configuration) the form part is not reloaded. When I return true, parameters are added to URL.. Am I clear ?

Comment: Of course the form is not going to reload with the values. If you want the form to page to have the new values why are you using Ajax and not using a normal form post??? If you want the page to reload, than onsuccess refresh the page. `window.location.reload();`

Comment: I got what I want! Thanks.. I update the post with the new function. But `return false;` seems like wrong approach.. Why I need to return false there or is there anything else i can use ?

Comment: You need to cancel the form action if you do not want it to submit, that is what you need to do!

Comment: ACtually I dont want to reload all page but `<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">` need to know the user login to hide login form. Now i dont have a solution except reloading the page. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Well if the server did not return any of the stuff in the for the authorized user, you would need to get that content. Up to you how you get it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle to test your code and have been unable to replicate your bug. The POST request appears to submit normally (going via the chrome dev tools), and no extra GET values are appearing for me.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5EXWT/1/

Out of interest, what version of jQuery are you using?

```
 {this is just here so i can submit the jsfiddle}
```

Comment: it is jquery.1.10.2.min.js . Can it be the reason ?

Comment: The jsfiddle is using 1.10.1, although i wouldn't imagine there'd be much difference between the two versions. Maybe worth adding a console log to your code to just confirm it is actually that bit of code thats responsible?

Comment: I havent done this console log before :) let me learn how to do it before trying it